Pagination buttons are suddenly disappearing when tried to delete some javascript code
In a commercial website I am making, I have been trying to test out the pagination buttons. But the problem is that for some reason the script that I applied to my index.html isn't working. I am following along a youtube video and planned to work my way through that, but I encountered the following issues:
1 - When I delete code from my script.js, any code actually, it causes my pagination buttons to disappear.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

    <head>
      
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Tech2etc Ecommerce Tutorial</title>
       
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/all.css" />

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="pagination.css">

   
    </head>

    <body>


        <!-- Pagination Buttons -->

        <div class="pagination-buttons">
  <button type="button" class="page-btn prev-page">prev</button>
  <button type="button" class="page-btn start-page">start</button>
  <button type="button" class="page-btn active">1</button>
  <button type="button" class="page-btn">2</button>
  <button type="button" class="page-btn">3</button>
  <button type="button" class="page-btn">4</button>
  <button type="button" class="page-btn">5</button>
  <button type="button" class="page-btn">6</button>
  <button type="button" class="page-btn">7</button>
  <button type="button" class="page-btn">8</button>
  <button type="button" class="page-btn">9</button>
  <button type="button" class="page-btn next-page">next</button>
  <button type="button" class="page-btn end-page">end</button>
</div> 

<script src="script.js" defer>  </script>

        
    </body>

</html>

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  padding: 25px;
  background: #fff;
  color: #111;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

*, *::after, *::before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

button {
  background: none;
  appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -ms-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.page-btn {
  background: #ddd;
  color: #2c303a;
  height: 35px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 0.1em;
  transition: background 0.3s ease;
  margin: 0 2px
}

.page-btn:first-of-type {
  margin-left: 0;
}

.page-btn:last-of-type {
  margin-right: 0;
}

.page-btn:not([class$="-page"]) {
  width: 35px;
}

.pagination-buttons {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.page-btn[class*="-page"] {
  background: #ccc;
  font-size: 0.6em;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.page-btn.active {
  background: #717790;
  color: #fff;
}

.page-btn[disabled] {
  opacity: 0.3;
}

2 - I also don't understand just how using this code:    would give me an extra pagination button since I don't really see any code that connects to the index.html containing that pagination container.

The closest seems to be this however this just creates an element, not retrieve it:
const paginationButtonContainer = document.createElement('div');
paginationButtonContainer.className = 'pagination-buttons';

const pageNumbers = (total, max, current) => {
    const half = Math.floor(max / 2);
    let to = max;
    
    if(current + half >= total) {
      to = total;
    } else if(current > half) {
      to = current + half ;
    }
    
    let from = Math.max(to - max, 0);
  
    return Array.from({length: Math.min(total, max)}, (_, i) => (i + 1) + from);
  }
  
  function PaginationButton(totalPages, maxPagesVisible = 10, currentPage = 1) {
    let pages = pageNumbers(totalPages, maxPagesVisible, currentPage);
    let currentPageBtn = null;
    const buttons = new Map();
    const disabled = {
      start: () => pages[0] === 1,
      prev: () => currentPage === 1 || currentPage > totalPages,
      end: () => pages.slice(-1)[0] === totalPages,
      next: () => currentPage >= totalPages
    }
    const frag = document.createDocumentFragment();
    const paginationButtonContainer = document.createElement('div');
    paginationButtonContainer.className = 'pagination-buttons';
    
    const createAndSetupButton = (label = '', cls = '', disabled = false, handleClick) => {
      const buttonElement = document.createElement('button');
      buttonElement.textContent = label;
      buttonElement.className = `page-btn ${cls}`;
      buttonElement.disabled = disabled;
      buttonElement.addEventListener('click', e => {
        handleClick(e);
        this.update();
        paginationButtonContainer.value = currentPage;
        paginationButtonContainer.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('change', {detail: {currentPageBtn}}));
      });
      
      return buttonElement;
    }
    
    const onPageButtonClick = e => currentPage = Number(e.currentTarget.textContent);
    
    const onPageButtonUpdate = index => (btn) => {
      btn.textContent = pages[index];
      
      if(pages[index] === currentPage) {
        currentPageBtn.classList.remove('active');
        btn.classList.add('active');
        currentPageBtn = btn;
        currentPageBtn.focus();
      }
    };
    
    buttons.set(
      createAndSetupButton('start', 'start-page', disabled.start(), () => currentPage = 1),
      (btn) => btn.disabled = disabled.start()
    )
    
    buttons.set(
      createAndSetupButton('prev', 'prev-page', disabled.prev(), () => currentPage -= 1),
      (btn) => btn.disabled = disabled.prev()
    )
    
    pages.map((pageNumber, index) => {
      const isCurrentPage = currentPage === pageNumber;
      const button = createAndSetupButton(
        pageNumber, isCurrentPage ? 'active' : '', false, onPageButtonClick
      );
      
      if(isCurrentPage) {
        currentPageBtn = button;
      }
      
      buttons.set(button, onPageButtonUpdate(index));
    });
    
    buttons.set(
      createAndSetupButton('next', 'next-page', disabled.next(), () => currentPage += 1),
      (btn) => btn.disabled = disabled.next()
    )
    
    buttons.set(
      createAndSetupButton('end', 'end-page', disabled.end(), () => currentPage = totalPages),
      (btn) => btn.disabled = disabled.end()
    )
    
    buttons.forEach((_, btn) => frag.appendChild(btn));
    paginationButtonContainer.appendChild(frag);
    
    this.render = (container = document.body) => {
      container.appendChild(paginationButtonContainer);
    }
    
    this.update = (newPageNumber = currentPage) => {
      currentPage = newPageNumber;
      pages = pageNumbers(totalPages, maxPagesVisible, currentPage);
      buttons.forEach((updateButton, btn) => updateButton(btn));
    }
    
    this.onChange = (handler) => {
      paginationButtonContainer.addEventListener('change', handler);
    }
  }
  
  const paginationButtons = new PaginationButton(10, 5);
  
  paginationButtons.render();
  
  paginationButtons.onChange(e => {
    console.log('-- changed', e.target.value)
  });
  

I tried commenting out blocks of code from the start of the script in order to figure out how the pagination button worked. I have been unable to do that however since any code that I deleted caused the buttons to keep on disappearing from my web page.


const pageNumbers = (total, max, current) => {
    const half = Math.floor(max / 2);
    let to = max;
    
    if(current + half >= total) {
      to = total;
    } else if(current > half) {
      to = current + half ;
    }
    
    let from = Math.max(to - max, 0);
  
    return Array.from({length: Math.min(total, max)}, (_, i) => (i + 1) + from);
  }
  
  function PaginationButton(totalPages, maxPagesVisible = 10, currentPage = 1) {
    let pages = pageNumbers(totalPages, maxPagesVisible, currentPage);
    let currentPageBtn = null;
    const buttons = new Map();
    const disabled = {
      start: () => pages[0] === 1,
      prev: () => currentPage === 1 || currentPage > totalPages,
      end: () => pages.slice(-1)[0] === totalPages,
      next: () => currentPage >= totalPages
    }
    const frag = document.createDocumentFragment();
    const paginationButtonContainer = document.createElement('div');
    paginationButtonContainer.className = 'pagination-buttons';
    
    const createAndSetupButton = (label = '', cls = '', disabled = false, handleClick) => {
      const buttonElement = document.createElement('button');
      buttonElement.textContent = label;
      buttonElement.className = `page-btn ${cls}`;
      buttonElement.disabled = disabled;
      buttonElement.addEventListener('click', e => {
        handleClick(e);
        this.update();
        paginationButtonContainer.value = currentPage;
        paginationButtonContainer.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('change', {detail: {currentPageBtn}}));
      });
      
      return buttonElement;
    }
    
    const onPageButtonClick = e => currentPage = Number(e.currentTarget.textContent);
    
    const onPageButtonUpdate = index => (btn) => {
      btn.textContent = pages[index];
      
      if(pages[index] === currentPage) {
        currentPageBtn.classList.remove('active');
        btn.classList.add('active');
        currentPageBtn = btn;
        currentPageBtn.focus();
      }
    };
    
    buttons.set(
      createAndSetupButton('start', 'start-page', disabled.start(), () => currentPage = 1),
      (btn) => btn.disabled = disabled.start()
    )
    
    buttons.set(
      createAndSetupButton('prev', 'prev-page', disabled.prev(), () => currentPage -= 1),
      (btn) => btn.disabled = disabled.prev()
    )
    
    pages.map((pageNumber, index) => {
      const isCurrentPage = currentPage === pageNumber;
      const button = createAndSetupButton(
        pageNumber, isCurrentPage ? 'active' : '', false, onPageButtonClick
      );
      
      if(isCurrentPage) {
        currentPageBtn = button;
      }
      
      buttons.set(button, onPageButtonUpdate(index));
    });
    
    buttons.set(
      createAndSetupButton('next', 'next-page', disabled.next(), () => currentPage += 1),
      (btn) => btn.disabled = disabled.next()
    )
    
    buttons.set(
      createAndSetupButton('end', 'end-page', disabled.end(), () => currentPage = totalPages),
      (btn) => btn.disabled = disabled.end()
    )
    
    buttons.forEach((_, btn) => frag.appendChild(btn));
    paginationButtonContainer.appendChild(frag);
    
    this.render = (container = document.body) => {
      container.appendChild(paginationButtonContainer);
    }
    
    this.update = (newPageNumber = currentPage) => {
      currentPage = newPageNumber;
      pages = pageNumbers(totalPages, maxPagesVisible, currentPage);
      buttons.forEach((updateButton, btn) => updateButton(btn));
    }
    
    this.onChange = (handler) => {
      paginationButtonContainer.addEventListener('change', handler);
    }
  }
  
  const paginationButtons = new PaginationButton(10, 5);
  
  paginationButtons.render();
  
  paginationButtons.onChange(e => {
    console.log('-- changed', e.target.value);
  });
  
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  padding: 25px;
  background: #fff;
  color: #111;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

*, *::after, *::before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

button {
  background: none;
  appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -ms-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.page-btn {
  background: #ddd;
  color: #2c303a;
  height: 35px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 0.1em;
  transition: background 0.3s ease;
  margin: 0 2px
}

.page-btn:first-of-type {
  margin-left: 0;
}

.page-btn:last-of-type {
  margin-right: 0;
}

.page-btn:not([class$="-page"]) {
  width: 35px;
}

.pagination-buttons {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.page-btn[class*="-page"] {
  background: #ccc;
  font-size: 0.6em;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.page-btn.active {
  background: #717790;
  color: #fff;
}

.page-btn[disabled] {
  opacity: 0.3;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

    <head>
      
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Tech2etc Ecommerce Tutorial</title>
       
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/all.css" />

       
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="pagination.css">

   
    </head>

    <body>

        <!-- Pagination Buttons -->


    <div class="pagination-buttons">
  <button type="button" class="page-btn prev-page">prev</button>
  <button type="button" class="page-btn start-page">start</button>
  <button type="button" class="page-btn active">1</button>
  <button type="button" class="page-btn">2</button>
  <button type="button" class="page-btn">3</button>
  <button type="button" class="page-btn">4</button>
  <button type="button" class="page-btn">5</button>
  <button type="button" class="page-btn">6</button>
  <button type="button" class="page-btn">7</button>
  <button type="button" class="page-btn">8</button>
  <button type="button" class="page-btn">9</button>
  <button type="button" class="page-btn next-page">next</button>
  <button type="button" class="page-btn end-page">end</button>
</div> 


<script src="script.js" defer >  </script>

        
    </body>

</html>





const pageNumbers = (total, max, current) => {
    const half = Math.floor(max / 2);
    let to = max;
    
    if(current + half >= total) {
      to = total;
    } else if(current > half) {
      to = current + half ;
    }
    
    let from = Math.max(to - max, 0);
  
    return Array.from({length: Math.min(total, max)}, (_, i) => (i + 1) + from);
  }
  
  function PaginationButton(totalPages, maxPagesVisible = 10, currentPage = 1) {
    let pages = pageNumbers(totalPages, maxPagesVisible, currentPage);
    let currentPageBtn = null;
    const buttons = new Map();
    const disabled = {
      start: () => pages[0] === 1,
      prev: () => currentPage === 1 || currentPage > totalPages,
      end: () => pages.slice(-1)[0] === totalPages,
      next: () => currentPage >= totalPages
    }
    const frag = document.createDocumentFragment();
    const paginationButtonContainer = document.createElement('div');
    paginationButtonContainer.className = 'pagination-buttons';
    
    const createAndSetupButton = (label = '', cls = '', disabled = false, handleClick) => {
      const buttonElement = document.createElement('button');
      buttonElement.textContent = label;
      buttonElement.className = `page-btn ${cls}`;
      buttonElement.disabled = disabled;
      buttonElement.addEventListener('click', e => {
        handleClick(e);
        this.update();
        paginationButtonContainer.value = currentPage;
        paginationButtonContainer.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('change', {detail: {currentPageBtn}}));
      });
      
      return buttonElement;
    }
    
    const onPageButtonClick = e => currentPage = Number(e.currentTarget.textContent);
    
    const onPageButtonUpdate = index => (btn) => {
      btn.textContent = pages[index];
      
      if(pages[index] === currentPage) {
        currentPageBtn.classList.remove('active');
        btn.classList.add('active');
        currentPageBtn = btn;
        currentPageBtn.focus();
      }
    };
    
    buttons.set(
      createAndSetupButton('start', 'start-page', disabled.start(), () => currentPage = 1),
      (btn) => btn.disabled = disabled.start()
    )
    
    buttons.set(
      createAndSetupButton('prev', 'prev-page', disabled.prev(), () => currentPage -= 1),
      (btn) => btn.disabled = disabled.prev()
    )
    
    pages.map((pageNumber, index) => {
      const isCurrentPage = currentPage === pageNumber;
      const button = createAndSetupButton(
        pageNumber, isCurrentPage ? 'active' : '', false, onPageButtonClick
      );
      
      if(isCurrentPage) {
        currentPageBtn = button;
      }
      
      buttons.set(button, onPageButtonUpdate(index));
    });
    
    buttons.set(
      createAndSetupButton('next', 'next-page', disabled.next(), () => currentPage += 1),
      (btn) => btn.disabled = disabled.next()
    )
    
    buttons.set(
      createAndSetupButton('end', 'end-page', disabled.end(), () => currentPage = totalPages),
      (btn) => btn.disabled = disabled.end()
    )
    
    buttons.forEach((_, btn) => frag.appendChild(btn));
    paginationButtonContainer.appendChild(frag);
    
    this.render = (container = document.body) => {
      container.appendChild(paginationButtonContainer);
    }
    
    this.update = (newPageNumber = currentPage) => {
      currentPage = newPageNumber;
      pages = pageNumbers(totalPages, maxPagesVisible, currentPage);
      buttons.forEach((updateButton, btn) => updateButton(btn));
    }
    
    this.onChange = (handler) => {
      paginationButtonContainer.addEventListener('change', handler);
    }
  }
  
  const paginationButtons = new PaginationButton(10, 5);
  
  paginationButtons.render();
  
  paginationButtons.onChange(e => {
    console.log('-- changed', e.target.value);
  });
  
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  padding: 25px;
  background: #fff;
  color: #111;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

*, *::after, *::before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

button {
  background: none;
  appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -ms-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.page-btn {
  background: #ddd;
  color: #2c303a;
  height: 35px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 0.1em;
  transition: background 0.3s ease;
  margin: 0 2px
}

.page-btn:first-of-type {
  margin-left: 0;
}

.page-btn:last-of-type {
  margin-right: 0;
}

.page-btn:not([class$="-page"]) {
  width: 35px;
}

.pagination-buttons {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.page-btn[class*="-page"] {
  background: #ccc;
  font-size: 0.6em;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.page-btn.active {
  background: #717790;
  color: #fff;
}

.page-btn[disabled] {
  opacity: 0.3;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

    <head>
      
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Tech2etc Ecommerce Tutorial</title>
       
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/all.css" />

       
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="pagination.css">

   
    </head>

    <body>

        <!-- Pagination Buttons -->


    <div class="pagination-buttons">
  <button type="button" class="page-btn prev-page">prev</button>
  <button type="button" class="page-btn start-page">start</button>
  <button type="button" class="page-btn active">1</button>
  <button type="button" class="page-btn">2</button>
  <button type="button" class="page-btn">3</button>
  <button type="button" class="page-btn">4</button>
  <button type="button" class="page-btn">5</button>
  <button type="button" class="page-btn">6</button>
  <button type="button" class="page-btn">7</button>
  <button type="button" class="page-btn">8</button>
  <button type="button" class="page-btn">9</button>
  <button type="button" class="page-btn next-page">next</button>
  <button type="button" class="page-btn end-page">end</button>
</div> 


<script src="script.js" defer >  </script>

        
    </body>

</html>




Edited Version (got rid of the first block of code in javascript):


  function PaginationButton(totalPages, maxPagesVisible = 10, currentPage = 1) {
    let pages = pageNumbers(totalPages, maxPagesVisible, currentPage);
    let currentPageBtn = null;
    const buttons = new Map();
    const disabled = {
      start: () => pages[0] === 1,
      prev: () => currentPage === 1 || currentPage > totalPages,
      end: () => pages.slice(-1)[0] === totalPages,
      next: () => currentPage >= totalPages
    }
    const frag = document.createDocumentFragment();
    const paginationButtonContainer = document.createElement('div');
    paginationButtonContainer.className = 'pagination-buttons';
    
    const createAndSetupButton = (label = '', cls = '', disabled = false, handleClick) => {
      const buttonElement = document.createElement('button');
      buttonElement.textContent = label;
      buttonElement.className = `page-btn ${cls}`;
      buttonElement.disabled = disabled;
      buttonElement.addEventListener('click', e => {
        handleClick(e);
        this.update();
        paginationButtonContainer.value = currentPage;
        paginationButtonContainer.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('change', {detail: {currentPageBtn}}));
      });
      
      return buttonElement;
    }
    
    const onPageButtonClick = e => currentPage = Number(e.currentTarget.textContent);
    
    const onPageButtonUpdate = index => (btn) => {
      btn.textContent = pages[index];
      
      if(pages[index] === currentPage) {
        currentPageBtn.classList.remove('active');
        btn.classList.add('active');
        currentPageBtn = btn;
        currentPageBtn.focus();
      }
    };
    
    buttons.set(
      createAndSetupButton('start', 'start-page', disabled.start(), () => currentPage = 1),
      (btn) => btn.disabled = disabled.start()
    )
    
    buttons.set(
      createAndSetupButton('prev', 'prev-page', disabled.prev(), () => currentPage -= 1),
      (btn) => btn.disabled = disabled.prev()
    )
    
    pages.map((pageNumber, index) => {
      const isCurrentPage = currentPage === pageNumber;
      const button = createAndSetupButton(
        pageNumber, isCurrentPage ? 'active' : '', false, onPageButtonClick
      );
      
      if(isCurrentPage) {
        currentPageBtn = button;
      }
      
      buttons.set(button, onPageButtonUpdate(index));
    });
    
    buttons.set(
      createAndSetupButton('next', 'next-page', disabled.next(), () => currentPage += 1),
      (btn) => btn.disabled = disabled.next()
    )
    
    buttons.set(
      createAndSetupButton('end', 'end-page', disabled.end(), () => currentPage = totalPages),
      (btn) => btn.disabled = disabled.end()
    )
    
    buttons.forEach((_, btn) => frag.appendChild(btn));
    paginationButtonContainer.appendChild(frag);
    
    this.render = (container = document.body) => {
      container.appendChild(paginationButtonContainer);
    }
    
    this.update = (newPageNumber = currentPage) => {
      currentPage = newPageNumber;
      pages = pageNumbers(totalPages, maxPagesVisible, currentPage);
      buttons.forEach((updateButton, btn) => updateButton(btn));
    }
    
    this.onChange = (handler) => {
      paginationButtonContainer.addEventListener('change', handler);
    }
  }
  
  const paginationButtons = new PaginationButton(10, 5);
  
  paginationButtons.render();
  
  paginationButtons.onChange(e => {
    console.log('-- changed', e.target.value);
  });
  
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  padding: 25px;
  background: #fff;
  color: #111;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

*, *::after, *::before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

button {
  background: none;
  appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -ms-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.page-btn {
  background: #ddd;
  color: #2c303a;
  height: 35px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 0.1em;
  transition: background 0.3s ease;
  margin: 0 2px
}

.page-btn:first-of-type {
  margin-left: 0;
}

.page-btn:last-of-type {
  margin-right: 0;
}

.page-btn:not([class$="-page"]) {
  width: 35px;
}

.pagination-buttons {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.page-btn[class*="-page"] {
  background: #ccc;
  font-size: 0.6em;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.page-btn.active {
  background: #717790;
  color: #fff;
}

.page-btn[disabled] {
  opacity: 0.3;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

    <head>
      
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Tech2etc Ecommerce Tutorial</title>
       
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/all.css" />

       
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="pagination.css">

   
    </head>

    <body>

        <!-- Pagination Buttons -->


    <div class="pagination-buttons">
  <button type="button" class="page-btn prev-page">prev</button>
  <button type="button" class="page-btn start-page">start</button>
  <button type="button" class="page-btn active">1</button>
  <button type="button" class="page-btn">2</button>
  <button type="button" class="page-btn">3</button>
  <button type="button" class="page-btn">4</button>
  <button type="button" class="page-btn">5</button>
  <button type="button" class="page-btn">6</button>
  <button type="button" class="page-btn">7</button>
  <button type="button" class="page-btn">8</button>
  <button type="button" class="page-btn">9</button>
  <button type="button" class="page-btn next-page">next</button>
  <button type="button" class="page-btn end-page">end</button>
</div> 


<script src="script.js" defer >  </script>

        
    </body>

</html>




I cannot reproduce this problem. Can you create a runnable snippet which shows it? It probably needs to include a relevant js file, otherwise I don't see how we can help. Also, what do you see when you use your browser devtools inspect facility (e.g. are the buttons still there in the DOM? What CSS is being applied to them?

Hello Haworth! What do you mean by browser devtools inspect facility? I am not really familiar with that term since I am still a beginner in web dev.  If what you mean is clicking inspect on a web page, my buttons are still there.  The CSS being applied is my pagination.css, which styles the buttons as shown in the screenshot. The code for that is in the first css code snippet.

Does anyone know how to get rid of the extra runnable snippets that show up? I put more than  I needed in my post. I tried resetting them after accessing the page that contains all the code but when I reset everything it still stayed there. Also regarding the javascript I am unsure what is causing my buttons in the edited version to be deleted. If someone can help clarify things for me that would be appreciated.

@AHaworth  I have made a runnable snippet. You can take a look at it, just ignore the extra one I created. That one was by accident.

When you delete code from your script.js, if the pagination buttons disappear, it's likely that the missing code is crucial for the buttons' functionality or rendering.
From the code you shared ensure that these methods are being called correctly. The render() method appends the buttons to the container, and update() updates their state. If these methods are not functioning as expected due to missing code, the buttons might not show up.
Here’s a simplified version of how you might ensure the pagination buttons are correctly displayed:
class PaginationButton {
  constructor(totalPages, maxPagesVisible = 10, currentPage = 1) {
    this.totalPages = totalPages;
    this.maxPagesVisible = maxPagesVisible;
    this.currentPage = currentPage;
    this.buttons = new Map();
    this.createButtons();
  }

  createButtons() {
    const container = document.createElement('div');
    container.className = 'pagination-buttons';

    const createButton = (label, cls, disabled, onClick) => {
      const button = document.createElement('button');
      button.textContent = label;
      button.className = `page-btn ${cls}`;
      button.disabled = disabled;
      button.addEventListener('click', onClick);
      return button;
    };

    container.appendChild(createButton('start', 'start-page', this.currentPage === 1, () => this.currentPage = 1));
    container.appendChild(createButton('prev', 'prev-page', this.currentPage === 1, () => this.currentPage -= 1));
    
    for (let i = 1; i <= this.totalPages; i++) {
      container.appendChild(createButton(i, i === this.currentPage ? 'active' : '', false, () => this.currentPage = i));
    }

    container.appendChild(createButton('next', 'next-page', this.currentPage === this.totalPages, () => this.currentPage += 1));
    container.appendChild(createButton('end', 'end-page', this.currentPage === this.totalPages, () => this.currentPage = this.totalPages));

    document.body.appendChild(container);
  }
}

const pagination = new PaginationButton(10, 5);

By carefully checking these aspects, you should be able to identify why the pagination buttons are disappearing and how to fix it.

Please don't just dump AI-generated answers here.
